# how to upgrade python to 2.7.10 on ubuntu12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

the default python version is 2.7.3,and i install python2.7.10 like this:

```
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
    tar xzf Python-2.7.10.tgz
    $ cd Python-2.7.10
    $ sudo ./configure 
    $ sudo make 
    $ sudo make install
```

then,the python is upgrade to 2.7.10

```
    root@ubuntu:/# python
    Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 29 2017, 10:24:22) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>
```

and install requests library:

```
    root@ubuntu:/# pip install requests
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): chardet>=3.0.2,=2.5,=1.21.1,=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests)
    Cleaning up...
    root@ubuntu:/#
```

but it says no module named requests

```
    >>> import requests
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named requests
    >>>
```

but how can i solve the problem?please...